# Проблема С падением (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я Делаю Игру По Типу "Geometry Dash" Используя Движок Unity В 3Д. В ней Мы Играем За Кубик (Как и в "Geometry Dash"). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Реализовав Базовые Механики я Столкнулся с проблемой:

> Если Прыгать, Всё Хорошо, но Если Упасть С Поверхности Не Прыгая, То Игрок Упадет, но с Очень Большой Скоростью

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Лично Я Не знаю В чём дело. Для Физики Я Не Использовал Rigidbody, А Использовал CharacterController.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.zero;
    CharacterController characterController;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpSpeed;
    public float gravity;
    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        moveVector.x = moveSpeed;

        if (characterController.isGrounded && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
            moveVector.y = jumpSpeed;
        moveVector.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        //transform.Rotate(0, 1, 0);
        characterController.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Лично Я Не Знаю Что Делать, так Что Помогите.

Comment: Вы В Поле Gravity Какое Значение Устанавливаете? Зачем Придумывать Свои Костыли, Когда Можно Использовать Встроенную Физику?

Comment: Значение 20. А про Костыли Сам Даже Не Знаю

Comment: В Этом И Проблема. Вы Установили Скорость Падения Высокую И Ждете, что Она Будет Нормальной. Вам В Данном Случае CharacterController Вообще Не Нужен. Используйте Перемещение Через RigidBody.velocity И Анимационные Кривые Для Реализации Прыжка.